# How to identify the different stages of experience in meditation?

Tags: meditation

In meditation when you see different color what does it mean? is everybody seeing the color?

Upanishad says that a light like lighting, white blazing light should engulf the person who meditates and his/her surrounding,

But in mediation only blue color is seen. How to change color according to  Upanishad?

Is blue color in mediation is it tamasic.. as it symbol of akasha (lord is ganesha i.e. lord of tamo guna)

Comment: You cant change color. Colors manifest themselves....You have no control in changing but when you progress, they change automatically!

Comment: "Lord Ganesha is the lord of Tamo Guna ..." Where did u learn abt this?

Comment: @Rickross As you know every guna has a diety,  I came to know from lectures of bannaje govindacharya.. that ganesh creation story is symbolic.. ganesha stays in every body navel, he is the first god to be prayed to take us upward, its like switch.. ganesh have the switch to take us uppward he is first step to take us upward..

Comment: As you know every guna has a diety" ---Yes the Manu Smriti says all deities are manifestation of Sattva... Rakshas, Pisachas animals etc all come from Tamo.. so how can a deity come from or related to Tamo? And Ganesh resides in muladhara not in navel.. @prasannaragothaman

Comment: @Rickross all devas including ganesh are sattvic.. but he can rule over one guna that is what is ment here

Comment: Okay thx for clarifying .. @prasannaragothaman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swami Sivananda had mentioned the different lights one sees in meditation.

Meditation / Experiences in Meditation / [Lights in Meditation](http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1722&parent=640&format=html):

> Various kinds of lights manifest during meditation owing to concentration. In the beginning, a bright white light, the size of a pin's point will appear in the forehead in the Trikuti, the space between the two eyebrows, which corresponds tentatively to the Ajna-Chakra of the astral body. You will notice, when the eyes are closed, different coloured lights, white, yellow, red, smoky, blue, green, mixed lights, flashes like lightning, like fire, burning char-coal, fire-flies, moon, sun, stars. These lights appear in the mental space, Chidakasa. These are all Tanmatric lights. Each Tanmatra has its own specific colour. Prithvi (earth) Tanmatra has a yellow-coloured light; Apas (water) Tanmatra has a white-coloured light; Agni (fire) Tanmatra has a red-coloured light; Vayu (wind) Tanmatra has a smoky light; Akasa (sky) Tanmatra has a blue light. **Yellow and white lights are very commonly seen. Red and blue lights are rarely noticeable. Frequently there is a combination of white and yellow lights. In the beginning, small balls of white light float about before the mind's eye.** When you first observe this, be assured that the mind is becoming more steady and that you are progressing in concentration. **After some months, the size of the light will increase and you will see a full blaze of white light, bigger than the sun.** In the beginning, these lights are not steady. They come and disappear immediately. They flash out from above the forehead and from the sides. They cause peculiar sensations of extreme joy and happiness and there is an intense desire for a vision of these lights. When you have steady and systematic practice of two or three hours in the morning, and two to three hours at night, these lights appear more frequently and remain steadily for a long time. The vision of the lights is a great encouragement in Sadhana. It impels you to stick steadily to meditation. It gives you strong faith also in superphysical matters. The appearance of the light denotes that you are transcending the physical consciousness. You are in a semi-conscious state when the light appears. You are between two planes. You must not shake the body when these lights manifest. You must be perfectly steady in the Asana. You must breathe very, very slowly.

Comment: @prasannaragothaman No need to focus on color. Different colors come automatically, Swami Sivananda has advised one to remain steady and continue with their meditation. These lights are only for encouragement that the one meditating is progressing well.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance my pranams

Comment: @prasannaragothaman You can also accept an answer (by clicking on the "tick" mark) if u are completely satisfied with it..